# Change a variable value to Proper Case in VBA?

Tags: string, vba, variables, case, title

I have a textbox, traditionally labeled as TextBox1, my TextBox1 accepts only Uppercase input (for names), but i'm using the same text to save the file in a folder, when i save i want the name of the person to be in Title case isntead, but I cant figure out how.

Here is what i got so far (i dont know how to use strings, so pardon if there is some werid mistake):

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim title As String
 title = TextBox1.Value
 Console.WriteLine (StrConv(title, VbStrConv.ProperCase))
 ' Proper Case /\

On Error GoTo Erro1
ChDir "C:\Modelos"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Modelos\MODELO - PACKING LIST.xlsx"
ChDir "C:\Users\andre.lins\Documents\Processos\Packs"
Tryagain:    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"C:\Users\andre.lins\Documents\Processos\Packs\PKDB\Packing list - " & TextBox1.Value & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False



GoTo Errorjump

Erro1:

escape = MsgBox("Qualquer alteração modificará o modelo, por favor, evite modificar o documento. Deseja salvar uma cópia?", vbYesNoCancel, "Atenção")

end sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This update to your code should do the trick:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim title As String
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook

    'As this code sits behind the command button on the form, ME is a reference to the form.
    title = StrConv(Me.TextBox1.Value, vbProperCase)

    'Set a reference to the workbook - code or user interaction may change the activeworkbook.
    Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Modelos\MODELO - PACKING LIST.xlsx")
    wrkBk.SaveAs "C:\Users\andre.lins\Documents\Processos\Packs\PKDB\Packing list - " & title & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Man, thank you so much! You are the best! f you knew how many time i tried to solve it... Have an amazing day !!! You deserve it (: