# How to Capitalize words not containing numbers in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a column of data in Excel with each cell words I would like to Capitalize (Proper) if they do not contain a number which may be important to remain UPPERCASE.

Example:
CARB REPAIR KIT CBR1000RR CBR600

I want to convert it to:
Carb Repair Kit CBR1000RR CBR600

Any word containing a number remains UPPERCASE, all other words are Capitalized

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change a variable value to Proper Case in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335774/change-a-variable-value-to-proper-case-in-vba)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would go with for each loop for splitting the cell in to array of words, and then to check each word, letter by letter with the isNumeric() function. The bolean variable, would be marked as true for the word if its a number, and such word will be left unchanged, other words will be changed to proper case. Each checked word is then being appended to the final string that being put back to the cell.

```vb
Sub capitalizeWords()
    Dim cll As Range
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim check As Boolean
    Dim final As String
    For Each cll In Selection
        arr = Split(cll.Value, " ")
        For Each element In arr
            For i = 1 To Len(element)
                If IsNumeric(Mid(element, i, 1)) Then
                    check = True                                                 
                End If            
            Next
                
            If check = False Then   
                final = final & " " & StrConv(element, vbProperCase)
            Else
                final = final & " " & element
            End If
        Next
            
        cll.Value = final
        final = ""
        check = False
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well for the format in my question, can it be adjusted for examples where the words with numbers come first?

Example:  CBR1000RR CARB REPAIR CBR600 KIT

Comment: @hamishmc replace the inner For loop with `check = element LIKE "*[0-9]*"`

Answer (score 2):

The function below returns a string that is modified as you describe.

```
Function ProperCase(ByVal Ref As String) As String

    Dim Sp()        As String           ' Split Ref into words
    Dim i           As Integer          ' loop counter: words
    Dim n           As Integer          ' loop counter: characters

    Sp = Split(Ref)
    For i = 0 To UBound(Sp)
        For n = Len(Sp(i)) To 1 Step -1
            If IsNumeric(Mid(Sp(i), n, 1)) Then Exit For
        Next n
        If n = 0 Then Sp(i) = StrConv(Sp(i), vbProperCase)
    Next i
    ProperCase = Join(Sp)
End Function
```

Run the procedure below to test.

```
Private Sub GetProperCase()
    Dim Sample As String
    
    Sample = "CARB REPAIR KIT CBR1000RR CBR600"
    Debug.Print ProperCase(Sample)
    Sample = "CBR1000RR CARB REPAIR CBR600 KIT"
    Debug.Print ProperCase(Sample)
End Sub
```

And here is a version of the function inspired by @Chris Neilsen's suggestion (which I have upvoted).

```
Private Function ProperCase(ByVal Ref As String) As String

    Dim Sp()        As String           ' Split Ref into words
    Dim i           As Integer          ' loop counter: words

    Sp = Split(Ref)
    For i = 0 To UBound(Sp)
        If Not Sp(i) Like "*[0-9]*" Then Sp(i) = StrConv(Sp(i), vbProperCase)
    Next i
    ProperCase = Join(Sp)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! My account is so new my upvotes don't show up but thanks for the helpful answer :)

Comment: You can't upvote but you can select the answer that solved your problem. In fact, that's how you earn the points you need to vote in the future.